# Can there be support for `code` in question titles?

Tags: feature-request

I find myself regularly writing or editing questions that have `code` in the title. It would be more legible if our Stack Exchange could support code formatting in the question titles. Is this possible?

Comment: Related on Meta SE: [Can I use inline code formatting in question titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125335/241919). Note that even the biggest programming site Stack Overflow doesn't have this.